# Implement infinite scroll with cdk scrolling module Angular 9, but relative to the viewport?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

I'm trying to build an infinite scroller with angular CDK scrolling module. Looking in the documentation I can't see a proper way to build an infinite scroller relative to the viewport and not to the elements. Is there a way to implement an infinite scroller without using:

```
*cdkVirtualFor="let item of items"
```

What I'm trying to do is scrolling a list with a header and some other elements at the top of the list before reaching the elements which needs to be rendered with an infinite scroller.
I can easily achieve this with ngx-infinite-scroll library, but I'd rather use angular CDK.

Comment: have you got sucess?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I'm still looking for an answer.

Comment: Is there any other plugin you know to perofrm inifinite scroll. Does ngx-infinite-scroll working sith angular 9 ivy

Comment: I'm currently using ngx-infinite-scroll and it's working fine with Angular 9.1.

Comment: Okay thanks. But after I downloaded it I got error it is not compatible with angular 9 ivy